# TFS 2015: How to exclude certain folders from triggering build with Git

Tags: git, tfs, build, continuous-integration, tfs-2015

I have several builds for the same Git repository using the new TFS 2015 Build system (CI, Deploy, Documentation, Database etc).

A check-in to any part of the Git-repo will now trigger all builds.

However, I want to trigger a Database build only when a check-in is performed in the Database folder and so on.  Is it possible to trigger build for subfolder(s) only and how?

Comment: There's no built-in way to do this in TFS 2015. However, if your folders are so independent that they have own build process each, it might make sense to split the repo in to several repos then.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can filter down to the folder level when using TFVC:

[image]

But with GIT team projects you can only filter at the trunk/branch levels currently:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/triggers#git-filters

You can include and exclude the folders in the triggers section, just remember to add "/" with the folder name.